# Is it possible to do something on all switch cases by default without repeating?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Is there a way to repeat a sentence inside of a switch for every case but for default? Without repeating the action inside every case, of course.

I have this:

```
this.set_estate = function(state){
    switch(state){
        case 'LOADING':
            current= est[state];
            break;
        case 'WRITING':
            current= est[state];
            //statements_2
            break;
        case 'WAITING':
            current= est[state];
            //statements_3
            break;
        default:
            console.log('tried to set state: '+state);
            break;
    }
}
```

And I'd like to know if it could be shifted into something similar to:

```
this.set_estate = function(state){
    switch(state){
        case 'LOADING':
        case 'WRITING':
        case 'WAITING':
            current= est[state];
            continue;
        case 'LOADING':
            //statements_1
            break;
        case 'WRITING':
            //statements_2
            break;
        case 'ESPERANDO':
            //statements_3
            break;
        default:
            console.log('tried to set state: '+state);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: set a default value to `current` of `current = est[state];` before starting the `switch` statement and only change it the `switch` statement if required? i.e. the `switch` is about dealing with the 'uncommon' cases?

Comment: You are right.. I think the same he needs..

Comment: No, once the switch finds the first matching value, it executes the instructions until a break or the end of the block. It does not re-evaluate the value. The `continue` statement is only for a loop, it does not change the switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write another switch statement before this to do just the common lines.  This would prevent you from writing the code multiple times, if that is your concern.